# Is it possible to dynamically append values into an object from an arraylist of objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Okay so i am having a bit of a brain fart here.

In the following code the length of `test` is unknown and can range from 1 to any number as per the user decides.

One sample value of `test` is included below. In the following code i am adding the values of `test` to the table object manually. But since the length of `test` is not fixed, I'm looking for a more dynamic approach but cannot figure out how.

For example:
Lets say the length of `test` is 3. I would like all 3 values of `test` to be automatically added to the table without any manual effort.

Sample value of test:

```
var test = []
for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    test.push([
        { text: 'Test1', italics: true, fontSize: 11 },
        { text: '2', alignment: 'center', fontSize: 11 },
        { text: '1', alignment: 'center', fontSize: 11 },
    ])
}
```

Table Object :

```
{
    table: {
        widths: ['50%', '25%', '25%'],
        headerRows: 1,
        body: [
            [{
                text: 'MES Module Name',
                bold: true,
                fillColor: 'lightgray',
                style: 'tableHeader'
            }, {
                text: 'Marks - Theory',
                bold: true,
                alignment: 'center',
                fillColor: 'lightgray',
                style: 'tableHeader'
            }, {
                text: 'Marks - Practical',
                bold: true,
                alignment: 'center',
                fillColor: 'lightgray',
                style: 'tableHeader'
            }],
            test[0],
            test[1],
            test[2],
            test[3],
            test[4],
        ]
    }
},
```

Comment: Arrays have `length` property, which gives you the largest index + 1.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `.concat()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this.

- Initialize `table.body = [];`
- Then use `table.body.push({});` to add new objects to that.

```
table.body = [];
for(var i=0; i<objectsToAdd.length; i++){
    table.body.push(objectsToAdd[i]);
}
```

Comment: YES! finally. That was my biggest brain fart ever. Thanks so much :)